# wordpress and form submition with jquery to php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms, form-submit

i'm trying to make options page for my theme in wordpress the file is options.php i'm haveing a problem to submit the form , i need to create a submit form function with java script , i have function that creates the form and function after it to save the values of the form so i can use it in my front-page.php

```
          <?php
              function create_form($options) {
                    echo "<form id='options_form' method='post' name='form' >\n";
                    foreach ($options as $value) {
                       switch ( $value['type'] ) {
                case "sub-section-3":
                    create_suf_header_3($value);
                    break;

                case "text";
                    create_section_for_text($value);
                    break;

                case "textarea":
                    create_section_for_textarea($value);
                    break;

                case "multi-select":
                    create_section_for_multi_select($value);
                    break;

                case "radio":
                    create_section_for_radio($value);
                    break;

                case "color-picker":
                    create_section_for_color_picker($value);
                    break;
            }
        }

        ?>
        <input name="save" type="button" value="Save" class="button" onclick="submit_form(this, document.forms['form'])" />
        <input name="reset_all" type="button" value="Reset to default values" class="button" onclick="submit_form(this, document.forms['form'])" />
        <input type="hidden" name="formaction" value="default" />

        </form>
    <?php }  ?>
         <script>

         function submit_form(element, form)
         {

         }
           </script>

             <?php

add_action('admin_menu', 'mynewtheme_add_admin');
function mynewtheme_add_admin() {
    global $themename, $shortname, $options, $spawned_options;

    if ( $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {
        if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['formaction'] ) {
            foreach ($options as $value) {
                if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) {
                    update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]  );
                }
                else {
                    delete_option( $value['id'] );
                }
            }

            foreach ($spawned_options as $value) {
                if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) {
                    update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]  );
                }
                else {
                    delete_option( $value['id'] );
                }
            }
            header("Location: themes.php?page=functions.php&saved=true");
            die;
        }
        else if('reset_all' == $_REQUEST['formaction']) {
            foreach ($options as $value) {
                delete_option( $value['id'] );
            }

            foreach ($spawned_options as $value) {
                delete_option( $value['id'] );
            }

            header("Location: themes.php?page=functions.php&".$_REQUEST['formaction']."=true");
            die;
        }
    }
    add_theme_page($themename." Theme Options", "".$themename." Theme Options",
        'edit_themes', basename(__FILE__), 'mynewtheme_admin'); }

function mynewtheme_admin() {
    global $themename, $shortname, $options, $spawned_options, $theme_name;

    if ($_REQUEST['saved']) {
        echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$themename.' settings saved for this page.</strong></p></div>';
    }
    if ($_REQUEST['reset_all']) {
        echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$themename.' settings reset.</strong></p></div>';
    }
    ?>
<div class="wrap">
    <h2>Settings for <?php echo $themename; ?></h2>
    <div class="mnt-options">
<?php
    create_form($options);
?>
    </div><!-- mnt-options -->
</div><!-- wrap -->
<?php } // end function mynewtheme_admin()
?>
```

Comment: What, specifically, is the problem? Are you getting an error? Have you tested other options that failed?

Comment: `case "text";` is a syntax error. It should be `case "text":` Just noting.